# docker-compose: Is it possible to share env variable within services?

Tags: docker-compose

I have docker compose file as follows.

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - var1 : 'localhost' 
      - var2 : 'root'
  api:
    environment:
      - var1 : 'localhost' 
      - var2 : 'root'
```

How can I share these env variables without declaring for each service?

is it possible to share env variables within services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can able to share environment variables using 'extends' option.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - var1 : 'localhost' 
      - var2 : 'root'
  api:
    extends: web # serveice api, will have access to all configs of web
```